# Changing the Font of Variables in an Equation Using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, formatting, fontspec, mathspec

I am trying to digitalize a book(130pages) by retyping it all(copy is in a really bad shape to be scanned). I am attempting to use Helvetica Neue as the main font for all numbers and variables on all equation. The font is installed in my machine but it clearly lacks some of the symbols like greek letters. I am doing this using XeLaTex. Here it is so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec} 


\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Helvetica Neue}

\begin{document}

 y = 1;
 moles O_2 = 12 \times 12 = 144

 \dfrac{1}{2}


 \log VP = A - \dfrac{B}{C + T}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to change the font of the Variables VP, A, B, C to Helvetica Neue. Is this possible?

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to begin with.